# python / how to declare a very large decimal variable and get very large decimals on operations such as division

Tags: python, decimal

using numbers like

`1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.3`
for example.

i'm very new to python and programming in general, sorry if i didn't asked right.

Comment: Are you just looking for large numbers, or large numbers with high precision? A `float` only keeps as much information as it can cram into 64 bits; if you want dozen of digits worth, you want to use `decimal.Decimal`. Start by reading [the module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html); there's a lot to learn, but it's worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring variables that large you can use **scientific notation**

http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/scientific.html

and to get "very large decimal values" on division operations you can use string formatting and scientific notation

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1vpmyl/how_do_i_convert_a_number_to_scientific_notation/

Comment: Yes, that was exactly  what i was looking for, thanks.